# How do I put a checkmark on a menu item that has submenu items. (Visual studio 2008 C++/MFC)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a menu that contains submenus.

eg:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3

  - item A
  - Item B

Item3 has items under it.

At any given time 1, 2, or the items under 3 should be checked.  Since I don't have an ID for Item3 I have to use the `MF_BYPOSITION` indicator when I try to set a check on Item3 to indicate one of its children has a checkmark.  Item3 should have a checkmark if A or B are checked.  I am able to check items 1 and 2 and A and B - but can't figure out item3.

I have not been able to successfully use either `::CheckMenuItem()` or `ModifyMenu()` to set the check mark.

Can someone point me to an example that does this successfully?  The docs seem to indicate it can be done, but I have been unable to do it.

EDIT

This is for a menu that is set as the menu for a dlg box.  The menu bar has three items - one of which drops down to what is shown above.

Note also, it is used as a popup for a right click, but I will take any suggestions to work in either case.

Comment: Is this a popup menu or part of the menu bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before for popup menus. You will need to access the submenu by position, instead of ID. Using your example above, Item 3 would be at position 2:

```
CMenu popupMenu;
popupMenu.LoadMenu(IDR_MYMENU);
popupMenu.GetSubMenu(0)->CheckMenuItem(2,MF_BYPOSITION|MF_CHECKED);
.
.
.
popupMenu.GetSubMenu(0)->TrackPopupMenu(...);
```

However, I haven't done this with items in the menu bar.

EDIT by Tim the OP:

For completeness

To get it to work with the menu item you have to get the hmenu

```
// MENU_POSITION is the zero based location of the menu you want to use. (file, edit, view, help... etc)
HMENU mainMenu = ::GetMenu(m_hWnd);
HMENU subMenu = GetSubMenu( mainMenu, MENU_POSITION);
SetMenuState(subMenu);
```

Comment: Well, it works for my popup/context menu but not for the menu bar one.  What a hassle.  There's got to be a way to do it that I have not tried.

Comment: I got it to work.  The problem was that I had been passing in HMENUs to a common method.  Depending on where it was called from it was either a right-click popup hmenu or the frame's hmenu.  THose can't be treated the same when using by position.  All other settings were done by id which works.

Answer (score 1):

A few moments ago I had a similar problem - a standard MFC menu bar containing at least one submenu, and the need to be able to add a check mark to the *submenu* parent item, when any of the submenu *child* items were checked.

The easiest solution (for me) turned out to be as simple as performing the update in the standard OnUpdateMenuItem(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) call. In my case I used ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI_RANGE() to feed a bunch of menu IDs into the same update call, but the principal is the same for a single ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI() map.

The code I used (edited to be more easily inserted into other people's work) is:

```
void CMyApp::OnUpdateMenu(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
   // Note, a submenu parent (which has no editable ID in the resource editor) has the SAME ID as the first child item
   if (pCmdUI->m_nID == ID_FIRST_CHILD_MENU && pCmdUI->m_pSubMenu != NULL) {
      // Get the child menu so we can see if any child items are checked
      CMenu* pSubMenu = pCmdUI->m_pSubMenu;
      BOOL fChildChecked = FALSE;
      for (UINT i = 0; !fChildChecked && i < pSubMenu->GetMenuItemCount(); ++i) {
         // Do something to decide if this child item should be checked...
         UINT nChildID = pSubMenu->GetMenuItemID(i);
         fChildChecked = IsThisChildChecked(nChildID);
      }

      // The POSITION of the current menu item is stored in pCmdUI->m_nIndex
      CMenu* pMenu = pCmdUI->m_pMenu;
      UINT flags = MF_BYPOSITION;
      if (fActiveChild) flags |= MF_CHECKED;
      pMenu->CheckMenuItem(pCmdUI->m_nIndex, flags);
   }

   // Set the enabled state of the menu item as you see fit...
   pCmdUI->Enable(TRUE);
}
```

*Et voilà* the submenu item automagically gains a check mark when any of its child menu items has a check mark.

Hope this helps others looking for similar solutions!

John